# How to Delete select rows from multiple tables using Join - CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, delete-row

I have three tables that I want to be able to delete select rows from, if a given condition in one of the tables is true. I am using codeigniter.

My Table Names are: Register, Profiles and Profilesmember. All 3 tables have the column "Email" which I want to Join on. One table "Register" has a unique column "is_email_verfiied" - which is either "yes" or "no". If it is "no", I want to delete the column from table "register" as well as one of the other two tables "Profiles" and "Profilesmember" depending on which contains matching entires in the 'email' column.

Here is my model:

```
    function databaseupdate ()
        {
        $verified = 'no';
        $tables = array('register', 'profiles', 'profilesmember');
        $this->db->from ('register');
        $this->db->join('profiles', 'profiles.email = register.email');
        $this->db->join('profilesmember', 'profilesmember.email = register.email');
        $this->db->where('register.is_email_verified', $verified);
        $this->db->delete($tables);
}
```

It deletes the correct entry from the table "Register", but does not from the second table Profilesmember or Profiles as the case may be.

The error message I get is

> "Unknown column 'register.is_email_verified' in 'where clause'".

I checked and the column "is_email_verified" is spelled correctly, and of course does exist in table Register (for clarity, this column does not exist in the other 2 tables).

The last SQL query is

> "DELETE FROM profiles WHERE register.is_email_verified = 'no' "

Comment: Probably something like `DELETE FROM profiles WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM register WHERE is_email_verified = 'no')`

Comment: If it was me I'd start with the sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed my approach and got rid of the JOIN idea - this works:

```
function databaseupdate ()
            {
            $verified = 'no';
            $tables = array('register', 'profiles', 'profilesmember');
            $this->db->select('email');
            $this->db->from('register');
            $this->db->where('is_email_verified', $verified);
            $query = $this->db->get(); 
            $email = $query->row()->email;
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->delete($tables);
            }
```